# Using Protractor element.all, how to select a day on a calendar element

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

The angular-ui datepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker ) is the component I'm selecting in a Protractor e2e test.

I can open the calendar as follows (which works just fine):

```
this.calendarClick = function () {
    var sel = '.calendar .glyphicon-calendar';        
    return element(by.css(sel)).click();
};
```

However, I would also like to select a particular day on the calendar.

Using jQuery, I can easily select all spans in the calendar:

```
$('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span')
```

which returns an array-like object:

```js
  
0:span.ng-binding.text-muted
1:span.ng-binding.text-muted
2:span.ng-binding.text-muted
3:span.ng-binding.text-muted
```

I can also use jQuery to select "01" on the calendar:

```
$('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span:contains("01")')

      [span.ng-binding, span.ng-binding.text-muted]
```

But using Protractor, how to select a particular day element on the calendar ?

I was thinking something like this to just click on the first day element:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span')).then(function (el) {
      console.log(el[0]);                            
      el.first().click();
 });
```

but it's throwing the error :

```
   TypeError: el.first is not a function
```

Advice is appreciated...

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the locator `by.cssContainingText` to get the element containing the text '01':

```
element(by.cssContainingText('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span', '01'))
  .click();
```

Or `.get` to get the element by index:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span'))
  .get(0)
  .click();
```

Or `.first` to get the first element:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span'))
  .first()
  .click();
```

Comment: This is helpful. I'm approaching it wrong by wrapping my click() event within a `.then()`.

Comment: This was the best fit for me, just using element.all() instead: `element.all(by.cssContainingText('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span', '01')).first().click();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same jquery selector that you have mentioned in the question to click the element.

```
$('[ng-click="select(dt.date)"] > span:[text="01"]').click()
```

Comment: I've read that, but I have to "turn on" the jquery option for Protractor, I believe.